# Is there any JQuery API to read the post value .?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, submit

Have a html page(one.html) consisting of a Input Text Box and submit button.

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="two.html">
<input type="text" value="" id="searchText">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Using the **method="post"**, am trying to **pass/post** the user entered text to **two.html**.

Is there any **Jquery API** that i can use to read the value in **two.html**.

Basically i need the user entered value to be inserted in HTML tag present in **two.html**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you're not using server side scripting, then you can't extract data unless you use `method="get"` as far as i know

Comment: no. you can post to a .html file, but javascript does not have any method of READING data that's posted to it. you can get GET query parameters fairly easily.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could attach a function to the submit button that sets a cookie, using javascript, and then read that cookie in `two.html`.  You could also set URL parameters/hashes and have `two.html` read them.  Neither of these would be a true "submit" though.

Comment: Thanks All.. Actually wanted to know without using the server side scripting and using only JavaScript/JQuery is there any way to read the post values.

Comment: So without server side it's pretty easy to emulate form submit. Just write the data to local storage, and listen for localstorage event in the second page code.

Comment: localStorage.searchText=$("#searchText").val(); and on two.html you have to use localstorage.searchText

Answer (score 0):

you don't need Jquery to read the posted value in two.html( if i got what you meant).. and i don't think jquery can read file from server unless using ajax or javascript cookies is other option.. anyways assuming this is what you want..simply post the form and get the posted value with `$_POST[]` in php

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="two.html">
 <input type="text" name="searchtext" value="" id="searchText">
 <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

two.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)
{
   echo '<div>'.$_POST['searchtext'].'</div>'
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks bipen, But am not using any server side scripting. Just pure HTML pages.

Comment: then creating form is useless... what you actually want.. i am getting confused.. :)

Comment: Bipen.. I think he wants to use posted value for two.html without using server side... :)

Comment: hehe.. i don't think he can do that... without server side code.. :) :)

Comment: Actually i am working on static HTML pages, where i need two HTML pages interact. so i wanted to know without using server side scripting is it achievable. Now i need to explore at the usage of PHP or HTML local storage.

Comment: @Kranky Why use forms if you don't want to do some server side scripting code. That way forms are useless.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to use POST? This can be done very easily with GET? But Italy are experimenting with POST, you're going to need to write a server side script.

Though this can be more complicated, because you need to have something running (assuming you're doing this on your own box) the server and something to execute the scripts, it's also quite easy once you get the basics down. There are many tutorials to get you started with this, but the basic principle is

One.html (post with data) -> server script processes data (redirects with processes data) -> two.html

Comment: Thanks Dave, was trying to achieve it without using any server side scripting.